# Xamarin Forms Hidden Application or service

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a service or app that gets the current location for user every minute, the issue is not in getting the location but the issue how to create app that still run in the background or run as a service even the user explicitly close the application.

I used Messaging center but it will stop when the user close app.

is there any way in xamarin where you can create a service which user can not interact with it ?

Comment: If the user explicitly "terminates" the app, well your services go away also: On Android use a foregrounded service, on iOS enable  background modes and location updates:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/foreground-services/  & https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/ios_backgrounding_walkthroughs/location_walkthrough/

Comment: what if the user close the application , is the foreground service still working or it will stop.

Comment: @moustafamalik  user close will not effect to foreground or background running, if user explicitly closed definitely it will close

Comment: The user can *always* force close/terminate an app... On android, a foregrounded service is placed into the notification bar (like a music player) and thus the **system** will not terminate it or doze it unnecessarily (unless there is a memory issue and the OS is forced too via its `OOM` service).

Comment: One way of explicitly close is going to seeing and seeing running apps and close

Comment: I would like to know if the user press navigation button (android ) and switch between running apps , and he choose to close my app (say app1). I know that app1 will be closed and will not be resides in memory  (as I test it using Messaging center ).my question here what is the best way to keep application updates (current location e.g.)  even the user close it ( not force close )

Comment: Services are not available in xamarin PCL, you need to use native Android and iOS features. Check AlarmManager for android and Background Fetch Interval for iOS. Have fun.

Comment: I use foreground service on android and it works successfully even the user close the application the service still running and updates database, I need to run the service when the device starts or reboot, and what is the equivalent scenario in IOS